# Best option for embedding fonts in webpage (SEO, speed, cross-compatibility)

Tags: css, fonts, seo, embedded-fonts

I have a font i've downloaded, its a True Type Font. I'm developing my own portfolio website so i'd like to get it fairly high up in Google (i can do the SEO for it) but i'm wondering what options i have for using this font for menu items, headings, etc..i've checked out Cufon but they wont let me upload it because it wasn't valid. I'd rather not use Flash..what other options have i got?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but an option would be to check out: http://code.google.com/webfonts

Comment: thanks for this, i've used this service before, works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontSquirrel is the best font converter. The free service even creates the CSS for you.

http://fontsquirrel.com

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you have online distribution rights for this font.

Fonts and SEO have nothing to do with each other. Page layout and proper HTML coding practices do.

Comment: Yes they do. If i choose to use images instead of normal html to achieve the font i want, this is going to affect SEO

Comment: There are already tried-and-true methods for using images. Fonts don't change that.

Comment: He's not saying there aren't methods.  He's saying he only wants people to post methods that are good for SEO.  The reason for this is that there exist methods of embedding fonts that aren't good for SEO (using images straight up without typing out the content somewhere in the code).

What you said: "Fonts and SEO have nothing to do with each other" is true, but it doesn't apply to the specifications of his post.